# Semisimple subgroups of $PSL_n(\mathbb C)$ are centerless

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

Since the protective special linear group $PSL_n(\mathbb C)$ is centerless. Is it true that any connected semisimple subgroup of $PSL_n(\mathbb C)$ is also centerless?

Comment: No: try to embed $SL_2$ into $PGL_3$.